# Colorbox working for the first time .. but not the second time .. I get a.removeEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Ok , so i am using colorbox to pop up windows of dynamic data generated by PHP .. Below is my php code ... when I click on the link , the windows pop up with the data .... but if I click on the same link again , the window doesn't get the information and I get this in the console `a.removeEventListener is not a function` , for the second time on clicking on the link for the colorbox to show .. 1st time works .. what could be going wrong ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var id_form;
            var url;
            $("a.madcomment").click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
             id_form = $(this).attr('id');
             url ="#madcomment_menu"+id_form; 
             $("a.madcomment").colorbox({inline:true, width:"350px", href:url});
             });


    });

    <?php
    $select  = "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS INNER JOIN Twitter_Data ON Twitter_Data.screen_name=Comments.Twitter WHERE Category ='Comments'";
          $result = mysql_query($select);
          $result_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
          echo " <table border =\"0\">";
          echo "<tr>";
          $user_array = array();
          $counter = 0;
          if($result_count > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  
     echo  "<div id ='scoring_scale' class='madscore".$row['ID']."' style='display:none;'>";
    echo "<div id='madcomment_menu".$row['ID']."' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>";
              echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."' class='green_circle' href='#'> +3 </a>";
              echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."' class='orange_circle' href='#'> +1 </a>";
              echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."' class='red_circle' href='#'> -1 </a>";
              echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."' class='brown_circle' href='#'> -3 </a><br />";
              echo"<form>";
              echo "<textarea id='text".$row['ID']."'rows='5' cols='33'>";
              echo "-";
              echo "</textarea>";
              echo"<button id='button".$row['ID']."'class='button_madscore'> MadComment </button>";
              echo "</form>";
              echo "</div>";
              echo "</div>";
    }

    }

    // Here is the link that will generate the COLORBOX pop-up

    echo "<a id='".$row['ID']."'class=' madcomment' href='madcomment_menu".$row['ID']."'><img src='images/madcomment.png' /> </a>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Based on my experience with colorbox, you need to defined $(".class-name").colorbox every time you add new content into the page, even if you have already defined for that class.  For example, if there are anchor elements of class "a.madcomment" upon loading the page and you call the $(a.madcomment).colorbox on $(document).ready, all the colorbox property will work properly.  However if you introduce new elements of the same a.madcomment after loading the page (through ajax or any other methods) you need to redefine the $(a.madcomment).colorbox property for the new elements.

Comment: @DavidZhanLiu Redefine it where exactly ??  can you show me a.madcomment is called with colorbox ..

Comment: I am not using AJAX , I am using just colorbox

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your colorbox each time on anchor click so in order to prevent this replace you colorbox code with below :

```
$.fn.colorbox({inline:true, width:"350px", href:url});
```

This will fix your issue.